# How to include @Html.Actionlink in C# text string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

While the @Html.Actionlink() helper is very convenient for building `<a>` elements in the .cshtml files, is it possible to construct them inside C# strings, such that they are subsequently rendered correctly in the HTML output?

For example, if I assign a string variable a value similar to the following:

```
Book.ReadMore = "Click @Html.ActionLink(\"this link\", \"About\", \"Home\") to read more.";
```

And then I try to display it (the literal text plus the link) through my .cshtml page, using code similar to:

```
<p>@Model.ReadMore</p>
```

All I get in the browser is the whole string exactly as I typed it, including the @Html... etc:

```
Click @Html.ActionLink("this link", "About", "Home") to read more.
```

Now, for proper SoC, I know that it's not the best of practices to have HTML stuff included in C# code, but is it at all possible to get the proper `<a>` link in this scenario, instead of the string itself?

**EDIT: More information** - This string is just one item in a collection of about 20-30 strings (displayed using a `for loop` in the View). Only a small handful of those items need a link (which is different in each case). Since, as mentioned above, I agree that it's obviously not good practice to use Razor/HTML in Model code, I'm trying to get a simple approach (if possible) which would give me the flexibility of building the link somewhere at the right place, while still yielding the maintainability of MVC SoC.

There must be a "right" way of doing this, which is simple yet maintainable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use MVC 3 @Html.ActionLink inside c# code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331041/how-to-use-mvc-3-html-actionlink-inside-c-sharp-code)

Comment: Highest voted (not accepted) answer on the above seems to have what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

Your model should not contain HTML, that's a view concern and belongs in view code.  Probably you should be using a Razor helper.

In your App_Code folder (create one if you don't have one), add a file, ReadMoreHelpers.cshtml:

```
@helper ReadMore() {
    <text>Click @Html.ActionLink("this link", "About", "Home") to read more.</text>
}
```

Then in any view:

```
@ReadMoreHelpers.ReadMore()
```

And that will output what you want.  If you *insist* on putting that property in your view, you could do:

```
Book.ReadMore = "Click " + @Html.ActionLink("this link", "About", "Home").ToHtmlString() + " to read more.";
```

Then in your view, make sure you use `Raw`:

```
@Html.Raw(Book.ReadMore)
```

However, I couldn't recommend more strongly that you do not put HTML in your model properties.

Comment: I certainly agree 100% about not having HTML in the model. With the more detailed scenario outlined in my edit to the original post, I'm looking for how to avoid it in fact. I wonder if it's possible (and follows best practices) to achieve clean separation by these steps: (a) In the Model, declare an enum of various tokens, then (b) also in the Model, include those tokens in the string items as required, and finally (c) build a Razor Helper to convert the enum'd tokens into those ActionLinks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The Razor view engine will interpret the ActionLink code during run-time while stuffing it as part of a C# string will be interpreted during compile time.