# Get the VirtualPath From the Area, Controller and Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I was wondering how to get a URL given the area, controller and action names. So far all I have managed to come up with is:

```
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);

if (routeData != null) {
    var virtualPath = routeData.Route.GetVirtualPath(new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData), new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "Pages", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }));

    if (virtualPath != null) 
        newNode.Url = "~/" + virtualPath.VirtualPath;
}
```

However it does not work. I was wondering if someone could help.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you need to do this? Do you have access to an HTTP Context? When you say that it doesn't work could you be a little more specific and explain the expected result and the actual result?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm trying to add it to an MVC SiteMap provider i found online. The one i found lacked area support so i figured i'd simply add that to the route value dictionary but that is not the case as the wrong route gets selected. I have a feeling it's something to do with the data tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase anyone is wondering, here's the solution I have come up with:

```
// Set the context
var context = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current),
    new RouteData());
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context);

// Set the url
var url = urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home",
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { area = "Pages" }));
```

I hope this helps someone.