# Get Area name in Views on render time at ASP.NET MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I use `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]` to get controller name or `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]` to get action name in views(actually in _Layout), but for area this `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Area"]` not worked. What is your suggestion to get area name in views programmaticaly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Get Current Area Name in View or Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723689/asp-net-mvc-get-current-area-name-in-view-or-controller)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Area name is **not** in the `RouteData.Values` but you can get it from the [DataTokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata.datatokens.aspx) collection::

```
ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"]
```