# Working of HTML/AJAX Helpers in .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, httpcontext

I think this might be pretty obvious for others but I cannot understand the working of these type of method overloads.
The ones in which we only pass **action method** name.

How does these `@Html.Helpers` get the expected **controller**?

My guesses:

1. That particular **Helper** extract it from the `HttpContext`
2. `this HtmlHelper htmlHelper` parameter holds all the information related
       to the request.

I am trying to create a **custom helper** in which user should pass the name of the action method and it **magically** gets its respective **controller**.

When I checked the `route-values` in `this HtmlHelper htmlHelper` during run-time they showed me this-

- {controller, Home}
- {action, Index}
- {id, null}

When I checked the `HttpContext` during run-time, it was `null`.

Expected output should be-

- {controller, Device}
- {action, Suggest}
- {id, null}

If someone can provide behind the curtains working of default `@Html.Helpers` with examples that will be great.

**UPDATE**
I did find what I was looking for.
Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748863/find-area-name-and-controller-name-in-custom-htmlhelper-with-asp-net-mvc3/9749647#9749647) to the question and its answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Html helpers have access to the HtmlHelper class. That reason is that these helpers are nothing else but extension methods of the HtmlHelper class.

```
 public static class HelperExtensions
 {
     public static string ControllerName(this HtmlHelper helper)
     {
               string name = helper.ViewContext.Controller.GetType().Name
               return String.Format("<span'>{0}</span>", name);
          }
     }
}
```

So everything regarding the current request is there.

View.cshtml

```
@Html.ControllerName()
```