# How do you get the current MVC Area name in a .cshtml file in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can get the current controller name and action name in a `_Layout.cshtml`  by doing the following

```
var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
var action = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

However when I try get the area

```
var area = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["area"].ToString();
```

it doesn't work as only 2 keys exist in that object("controller" and "action")

I examined the `ViewContext.RouteData` object and cannot get a value for the current Area name.

The [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723689/asp-net-mvc-get-current-area-name-in-view-or-controller) for the previous version of `ASP.net` don't work for me.

Comment: Try using RazorViewEngine.GetNormalizedRouteValue(ViewContext, "area").

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to Pranav's comment! `GetNormalizedRouteValue` method [is now public](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/1c8f22058c50efd5c7f8e714cb171611fa1dcbb8). So you can call `RazorViewEngine.GetNormalizedRouteValue` method in your view to the the area name when you pass the key as "area".

```
<h2> @RazorViewEngine.GetNormalizedRouteValue(ViewContext, "area") </h2>
```

`RazorViewEngine` class belongs to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor` namespace.  So make sure you have a using statement to import that in your view.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor
```

`GetNormalizedRouteValue` method is doing the same as explained in the previous version of answer. You can [see the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1c8f22058c50efd5c7f8e714cb171611fa1dcbb8/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor/RazorViewEngine.cs#L151) here

---

This totally worked for me in a razor view (MVC6).

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Routing
@{        
    var myAreaName = string.Empty;
    object areaObj;
    if (ViewContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("area", out areaObj))
    {
        myAreaName = areaObj.ToString();
    }
}

<h1>@myAreaName</h1>
```