# Get ASP.NET MVC area in Global.asax

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, global-asax, asp.net-mvc-areas

Is there a way to get the ASP.NET MVC area in the global.asax, specficially the method below?

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
        {
            if (arg.ToLower() == "username" && context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return context.User.Identity.Name;
       
            return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg);
        }
```

Comment: It seems you're going to employ strange logic in your application. Let us know the main purpose to suggest a better and more logical solution followed by correct design patterns in an Asp.net web application.

Comment: Clear a cache in a area is not strange lol

Comment: Please describe more. What type of clearing? Your code doesn't show sth like clearing a cache.

Comment: Sorry, As a 10 year Asp.net developer, I can't understand what you mean ! Describe more, otherwise no more help from me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the solution found in [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15953971/761468)?

`HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"]`

Comment: I went ahead and used this, perfect `context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"]`