# How to get current area name in the "OnActionExecuting" event of action filter?

Tags: asp.net-core

In Asp.Net Core, How it's possible to get the current area name in the OnActionExecuting method of action filter?

I tried the below statement, but it's returning me null at all times.

```
var area = context.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution and working with Asp.Net core 5.0 also:

```
ViewContext?.ActionDescriptor?.RouteValues["area"]
```

Thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55025419/1596971